# Twig: {% block %} and extend

Tags: symfony, twig

I am trying to override a {% block %} in a file (index.html.twig) that extends the file where the block is used (base.html.twig). But the extending file is including another twig file (feature.twig) where the block that overrides the content in index.html.twig is placed.
Is that possible in any way? Maybe with something else than the include statement?

```
{# index.html.twig #}
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{{ include('feature.html.twig') }}

{# base.html.twig #}
{% block extraJs %}{% endblock %}

{# feature.html.twig #}
{% block extraJs %}<script>$('...');</script>{% endblock %}
```

Comment: `include` returns the rendered version, so I don't think you can do anything with this setup.

Comment: Includes cant change the block of the template who included them

Comment: Please read the updated question

Comment: There is something like `embed` http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/embed.html but I don't think it resolve your problem, sorry.

Comment: Can you give an example of the input of the `extraJS`?

Comment: As `index` extends `base`, why not do it the easy way and (in `index`) declare: `{% block extraJs %}{{ include('feature.html.twig') }}{% endblock %}`. And in `feature` just render the content, no blocks.

Comment: Thanks @Yoshi, that worked for me. Do you want to add it as an answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`include`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html)-function (or tag) only ever *embeds* the **rendered** result. It is not possible to manipulate blocks in the including file.

But in your case this is not necessary. Because `index.html.twig` extends `base.html.twig`, you can overwrite the block `extraJs` like so:

```
{# index.html.twig #}
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block extraJs %}
    {{ include('feature.html.twig') }}
{% endblock }
```

---

If needed you can *extend* the original block by using the [`parent`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/parent.html)-function. E.g.:

```
{# index.html.twig #}
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block extraJs %}
    {{ parent() }} {# `extraJs`-block content from `base.html.twig` #}
    {{ include('feature.html.twig') }}
{% endblock }
```

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible. `include` just render template and include the output. You can't override block using it. Here is a issue related to this problem https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/1360

Answer (score 0):

Just as an info,I think you cannot put comments {# index.html.twig #} before the {% extends 'base.html.twig' %} and comments as I understood must be put always in blocks,hope this helps

Comment: Yes, this might be true. I put in in only to make clear how the different files are named.

Comment: Ok,no worries :)